# Programmatically Control The Scrolling Speed of ScrollView Android

Tags: android

I have a `TextView` inside a `ScrollView`. I have used the below code to scroll programmatically.

```
mScrollView.post(new Runnable() { 
                    public void run() { 
                         mScrollView.scrollTo(0, mScrollView.getBottom());

                    } 
            });
```

It does fine. Now But I want to control the scrolling speed of scrollview in differend speed values.
How to get it?

Answer (score 3):

Or you can animation for smooth scrolling

```
ObjectAnimator animator=ObjectAnimator.ofInt(yourScrollView, "scrollY",targetYScroll );
animator.start();
```

Comment: I had seen this answer somewhere just before, anyways, it worked for me by adding a code :
animator.setDuration(9000);
Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2):

After few searches, this is what worked for me.
Here is the code I used to slow down the scroll speed of ScrollView programmatically,

```
 ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mScrollView, "scrollY", mScrollView.getBottom());                               
 anim.setDuration(9000);                     
 anim.start();
```

mScrollView - Your ScrollView

```
mScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
```

`anima.setDuration(int Value)` - greater the value, slower the scroll I used the code block in `Switch` Button `OnCheckedChangedListener`.

Comment: you should update your answer with solution. and accept the answer which helped.